# Retrieving ID from Javascript - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

In my javascript code, i am able to output the id of a the selected item. I want to pass the id to my controller. I appended the input(created in the JS code) to my html form so as to get the id of the selected item but it wouldn't do the trick.

*HTML**

```
 <form>

// inputs for form in here

</form>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".myItem").append(
        '<p  name="item_id" id="item_id">Item ID: ' + item.id + '</p>').appendTo('form');
```

**Controller**

```
$getID = Input::get('item_id');
$fetchItem = Item::all()->where('id',$getID)->first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to append an `input` element instead of a `p`:

```
$(".myItem").append(
        '<input  name="item_id" id="item_id" value=' + item.id + ' />).appendTo('form');
```

You can even have both; 1 to store the value (`input`) and the other to show it on screen (`p`).

```
$(".myItem").append('
  <input type="hidden"  name="item_id" id="item_id" value=' + item.id + ' />
  <p>Item ID: ' + item.id + '</p>').appendTo('form');
```